# Add class to div in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, class

i try to add class in javascript to div, but it doesnt work.
Here's the div where I want to add class on it:

```
postimage.style.container = {"margin-bottom": "0.5em", "margin-top": "0.5em"};
```

I try to 
`container.className += ' additionalClass';` or
    `container_div.setAttribute('class',"classname")` but it doesn't work

I tried this, bu it doesn't work for me [Change an element's class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-class-with-javascript)

Comment: container is a div? Why do you reference it through style?

Comment: yes its div. Looks like https://image.prntscr.com/image/FGSl9DXvSQybCEeYx2qIDA.png